# How to randomly play multiple audio files in audio tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I am trying to randomly play file sound when I click on a link. I have multiple links which currently play one sound on each link when clicked.

```
<audio id="audio-fail">
  <!--<source src="" type="audio/mpeg"> -->
  <source src="/application/sounds/other/fail_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I have added another source:

```
<audio id="audio-fail">
  <!--<source src="" type="audio/mpeg"> -->
  <source src="/application/sounds/other/fail_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="/application/sounds/other/fail_2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

In jquery I read the file like this:

```
const failSound = $('#audio-fail')[0];
$('.js-clickable-object').on('click', function (e) {
   ailSound.play();
});
```

My question is how can I randomly play file source from the audio tag when clicked on a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have one audio tag contain multiple different source tag for this purpose because browser play first file that is supported.

So you need to store source of audios in array and on click event generate random number between 0 and length of array  and find target source by generated index. At the end set file address in `src` attribute of source tag.

```js
var src = [
  "http://free-mobi.org/files/ringtones/1/by_richy.mp3",
  "http://free-mobi.org/files/4/sleepy.mp3",
  "http://free-mobi.org/files/4/good_morning_alarm.mp3",
  "http://free-mobi.org/files/ringtones/1/otis_redding.mp3"
];

$('button').on('click', function (e) {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * src.length);
  $('#audio-fail source').attr("src", src[rand])  
  $('#audio-fail')[0].load();
  $('#audio-fail')[0].play();
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio-fail">
  <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<button>Play</button>
```

Because snippet doesn't play audio, i created demo in [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uqyxdp0g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the tasks is below. I believe there is a better solution.

```
<audio id="audio-fail">
        <source src="/application/sounds/other/fail_1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio id="audio-fail_again">
        <source src="/application/sounds/other/fail_2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

javascript below:

```
const multipleFailSounds = [$('#audio-fail')[0],$('#audio-fail-again')[0] ];

var randomSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * (multipleFailSounds.length));                
multipleFailSounds[randomSelection].play();
```

Feel free to post other solution if you think it's better. I just needed a quick fix.